# Negative cluster number in cluster assignment, SPSS Two Step Clustering

Tags: spss

running SPSS Two Step Clustering analysis, and requesting a new column be added with cluster assignment. This column is created with mostly positive values, but I notice several -1 values. Does someone know what this means?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it's the outlier cluster.